# delete element from list,which code style is better?

Tags: java, list

delete element from list,which code style is better?
1:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if(condition) {
                newList.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }
```

2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size();) {
            if(!condition) {
                list.remove(i);
            }else {
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Depends on whether you still need the old list or not.

Comment: I wonder the same question maybe the first one it looks better

Comment: Since Java 8, I would use Streams. Look at this examples: https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-remove-elements and this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-use-remove-item-stream

Comment: Lambdas are the way to go.

Comment: Or just use [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Answer (score 4):

Neither, because you shouldn't use index `for` loops to iterate a `List`.

The point of declaring the variable as a `List`, not an `ArrayList`, is that you can choose a different list implementation, e.g. `LinkedList`, and the code will continue to function correctly. However, `get(index)` is very slow for `LinkedList`. Instead, use an enhanced `for` loop, or use an `Iterator`.

If you want a new list, and leave the existing list unchanged, use an enhanced `for` loop:

```
// Get new list with some elements removed
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String value : list) {
    if (condition) {
        newList.add(value);
    }
}
```

If you want to modify the existing list, use an `Iterator`:

```
// Remove elements from existing list
for (Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    String value = iter.next();
    if (! condition) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

In Java 8+, you can do either way using streams / lambdas:

```
// Get new list with some elements removed
List<String> newList = list.stream()
        .filter(value -> condition)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```
// Remove elements from existing list
list.removeIf(value -> ! condition);
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need the old list, it is better to use the second approach as it will save space.
A more elegant way to delete an element from a list is to use an iterator.

```
Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String val = iter.next();
    if (!condition) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

In this case you will not have to create a new list or keep track of the index.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The most recommended way to iterate a List is declarating a datatype of your List.

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String element: oldList) {
    if(condition) {
        newList.add(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java streams and lambdas to do it in a cleaner way.

```
list = list.stream()
            .filter(condition)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here condition will have to be written as a lambda expression.

Example:

```
list = list.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.length() > 3)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

*collect the item(s) to delete into a new collection eg. another* `ArrayList` *and delete it/them at the end:*

```
…
List<String> delList = new ArrayList<>();
list.forEach( s -> {
    if( ! condition )
      delList.add( s );
  } );
list.removeAll( delList );
```

— `forEach` is faster than any `iterator` solution
— to collect the small number of to-delete-items is faster than to copy nearly the whole original list
— uses `forEach` instead of `for` with `get(i)`